# I want to show the title of an image when i use photogrid and colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

i'm using photogrid and colorbox to show pictures. I want to include the title of the image in the colorbox presentation, but i can't find which function is must use.

In the body i have:

```
.
<img src="albums/a-2/trein-3.jpg" title="Januari 2014 - Heerlen">
<img src="albums/a-2/trein-4.jpg" title="Januari 2014 - Heerlen">
.
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.my-example-grid').photosetGrid({
    highresLinks: true,
    rel:'whithhearts-gallery',
    gutter:'1px',
    layout:'1311411141',
    onComplete: function(){
    $('.my-example-grid').attr('style','');
    $('.my-example-grid a').colorbox({
     photo: false,
     scalePhotos: true,
            title:function () {
              <--what code??? ,
     maxHeight:'90%',
     maxWidth:'90%'
    });
    }
    });
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: please provide code with jquery in fiddler....

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't forget to accept answers if they have correctly answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
title: function () {
    return $("img", this).attr("title");
}
```